# Do you know any tools like smush.it I could on command line?

Tags: linux, image, optimization

You may know http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ it is a tool to optimize images (png, jpg, gif)

I'd like to implement a phing task or something, so I'm looking for a similar tool to be used on cli.

I know that smushit is a bundle of several tools, but I don't have time to pack them all together.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wish someone would build a tool for this very reason, I need a complete package I can pass all my images to with Phing that would do the smush.it process locally.  I would imagine ppl would even pay for something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Image Magick toolkit: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/ 
 You can can convert,transform, rotate, up/down scale, overlap , etc. It is available is pretty much all linux distros I know of.

Answer (score 2):

What OS? For Windows, PNGSlim from http://people.bath.ac.uk/ea2aced/tech/png/pngslim.zip is a nice commandline tool. It's a batchfile that runs the same file through a variety of different optimising tools that are out there, and keeps the best of what it gets (or reverts to a backup made at the beginning if it doesn't manage to shave off at least one batch).

Because of commandline limits, it can only do a handful of PNGs at a time, but because it's commandline, it's easy to script something to pass a whole directory through it.

It's pretty slow, but it is being thorough after all; one to leave running overnight.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I hope it may help other people, however (mea culpa, I edited my question) I'm looking for a tool that runs on linux

Comment: Well, at least then I will hopefully see some such answers. I'm looking for a Linux equivalent myself. Not actively, I haven't even bothered checking which if any of the tools PNGSlim uses are available on Linux yet, but it has been at the back of my mind to check.

Comment: Then, you may be interested in the tools SmushIt uses: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/faq.html#faq_crushtool

Comment: Cool. And yes, there's a definite overlap there with what PNGSlim packages together.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you might want to check out [littleutils](http://littleutils.sourceforge.net).

To install on Ubuntu / Debian:

Download littleutils

```
wget -O littleutils.tar.bz2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/littleutils/files/latest/download
```

Unzip / Untar

```
tar jxvf littleutils.tar.bz2
```

Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install gifsicle pngcrush lzip libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libjpeg-progs p7zip-full
```

`cd` into the littleutils directory (check version number)

```
cd littleutils-1.0.27
```

Configure and install

```
./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install && sudo make install-extra
```

You'll then be able to use `opt-jpg {filename}`, `opt-png {filename}` and `opt-gif {filename}` direct from the command line.